# Where condition in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot, where-clause

I am trying to create an application using Ruby On Rails and MongoDb as backend. And I am using FactoryGirl for testing.

As I am new to these technologies, I am not sure if I could use where condition and query the data in the model in FactoryGirl. And help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: when generating an item via FactoryGirl, you want it to first examine data that already exists in the DB, then use those data to determine how to construct the generated item. Did I read your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, it's difficult to give specifics, however, if you look at [Lazy Attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes) in the FactoryGirl documentation, you'll see this example:

```
factory :user do
  # ...
  activation_code { User.generate_activation_code }
  date_of_birth   { 21.years.ago }
end
```

Notice the **activation_code** and **date_of_birth** attributes -- They are using lazy attributes to get a value during build time.  The block definition (curly brackets) allows you to write any Ruby code (including doing ActiveRecord queries of existing data).  The result of this block will be assigned to that attribute.